# Bootstrap Daterange Picker Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I'm trying to add the daterange picker to my html file but cannot get it to show when i click on the input box. It works for datepicker, but i want it to offer to click on the range of dates. I've been struggling with these for days now and could really use some help. Extracted code is below. What am I missing?

```
`<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.daterange').daterangepicker();
</script>
```

try this.. may be it will help

Comment: Didn't help, still having the same issue. But thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is working as per your code.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
```

I have created a fiddle for you. Please check it here

https://jsfiddle.net/nonh3gr7/

Also please do check in your html file if there any script conflict or something happened?

Comment: it does work in the fiddle. However, when I try to open the html file (exactly as it is posted in my question, nothing added) in Google Chrome, it doesn't show. Only when I double click the input field, it drops down into one line with the same dates as in the placeholder value.

Comment: Then i think your internet connection is blocking the js files to use remotely. Please download and refer it locally. Try it.

Comment: I did and it still doesn't work. What's weird is I have a similar example for datepicker (no range, just to pick one date) and that wirks without any problem. Will keep trying to figure this out. Thanks for the idea Biby:)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the code check the working sample below

Here is a working JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k956L4ep/

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
```

Comment: Yes, the fiddle works, but for some reason when I run this html file (as it is posted) in Chrome, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: inspect your webpage, check your console